# Using gpu for tensorflow's calculation on raspberry pi

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, raspberry-pi3

I am developing robot with computer vision on Raspberry Pi 3 with Tensorflow. Can I use gpu for deep learning on raspberry pi 3?

Comment: Probably not, as currently only CUDA GPUs are mostly supported.

Comment: Thank you, dude :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE :

Here is an alternative backend for Keras [called plaidml](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml) that is not Tensorflow. The major selling feature is a speedup on non-Nvidia graphics cards.  It still isn't Tensorflow, but it may be a viable option.

HERE IS MY OLD ANSER PRIOR TO 2018-09 :

The short answer is no, it isn't possible at this time since Tensorflow leverages Nvidia drivers to power Nvidia GPUs and Raspberry Pi does not have Nvidia hardware.

One of two things have to change for you to have access to GPUs for a small form computing, Tensorflow has to support OpenCl [(tracked here)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22), or you have to switch platforms to something that has a Nvidia GPU like [this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3178059/hardware/nvidias-pascal-powered-jetson-tx2-computer-blows-away-raspberry-pi.html)

Sorry to be the bringer of bad news.

Comment: I just tried on a Rasbperry 3+ and got a `No OpenCL devices found`. I didn't tested it but it looks like VC4CL (https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL) could be working but you have to build it from source and be aware that you'll have to run your code as root if you want to access the GPU